# Trying to send email causes a break in my axamarin.forms ndroid app

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geocoding

The above header refers.

Here is the code:

```
private async Task SendEmailAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        var locationFromPhone = await GetLocationFromPhone().ConfigureAwait(false);

        _location = locationFromPhone;
    }

    string subject = "Abuse Alert (TM) Notification";
    
    string body = "An audio recording has just been sent to you as an attachment from the Abuse Alert (TM) Mobile App. " +
                  "You are receiving this message because your email address is among those picked for this exercise. " +
                  "This audio recording was done at this location: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=(" + _location.Latitude.ToString() + "," + _location.Longitude.ToString() + "). " +
                  "If you would like to stop receiving such messages in the future, kindly contact the App Admin ASAP. Thanks.";

    var mail = new MailMessage();
    var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.234Aproko.com", 25); //"smtp.gmail.com", 587);

    mail.From = new MailAddress("info@234Aproko.com"); //"softworldng@gmail.com");

    mail.To.Add("softworldng@gmail.com"); // info@234Aproko.com"); //1
    mail.To.Add("softworldng@live.com"); //2
    mail.To.Add("md.idiake.ng@outlook.com"); //3
    mail.To.Add("md.idiake.us@outlook.com"); //4
    mail.To.Add("md.idiake.ng@gmail.com"); //5
    mail.To.Add("softworldng@yahoo.com"); //6
    mail.To.Add("md.idiake.us@gmail.com"); //7

    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;

    Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new Attachment(recorder.GetAudioFilePath());
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    try
    { 
        smtpServer.Send(mail);
        
        await DisplayAlert("AbuseAlert", "Your audio was successfully uploaded via email.", "OK");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("AbuseAlert", "An authentication error may have occured with uploading your recorded audio via email. Pls, check that you have internet access and try again. If this issue persists, pls contact the App ADMIN ASAP...", "OK");             
    }
}
```

I believe the error occurs at the point I am trying to convert the latitude & longitude values to string. What is the correct way to do that so I can include both values in the email I am sending out?

Comment: you mention "break" and "error" but don't provide any actual useful description of either.  What is the specific exception?  What line causes it?  Either look at the stack trace or use the debugger to determine which line it is.

Comment: There is no error that is displayed. The app just stops at the point I tap on the Upload email button. I found out that when I comment out the line involving the latitude and longitude conversions to string, the email is sent successfully. So, I am suspecting that _location.Latitude.ToString() & _location.Longitude.ToString() are not giving me the string values I am expecting. This happens on my Android 9 phone. On the emulator, when I tap on the upload button, it does nothing.

Comment: If location access is not allowed for that app, you could get null value for `_location`, is it not?

Comment: does `locationFromPhone` contain valid data?

Comment: Xamarin seems to have issue with getting location on Android 11, see xamarin github [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1861). But you say you are running Android 9, check again if `_location` object is having value before you access the Lat & Long values.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Comment: Ok. Let me check.

Comment: *"There is no error that is displayed"* - sounds like VS isn't pausing when it encounters an exception. Go to VS menu Debug / Windows / Exception Settings. Make sure "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is CHECKED. Then if you run under debugger, it will stop at the line the exception happens.

Comment: Or wrap the suspect code in a try/catch

Comment: ok. Let me try that.